# Finding a third vertex of N-dimension equilateral triangle

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, linear-algebra

Given two vectors X and Y, where the number of elements in each is 5. Find a V vector that satisfies :
||X-V||=||Y-V||=||X-Y||

(X,Y,V) are the vertices of an equilateral triangle.
I have tried the following:
To get a vector V that is perpendicular to A and B :

```
import NumPy as np
# Example vectors

x = [ 0.93937874, 0.05568767, -2.05847484, -1.15965884, -0.34035054]
y = [-0.45921145, -0.55653187, 0.6027685, 0.13113272, -1.2176953 ]
# convert those vectors to a matrix to apply SVD (sure there is a shorter code to do so)
A_list=[]
A_list.append(x)
A_list.append(y)
A=np.array(A_list) # A is a Numpy matrix   
u,s,vh=np.linalg.svd(A)
v=vh[-1:1]
```

From here, what should I do? assuming that what I have done so far is correct

---

Comment: My first step showed in the code above may not be correct. I included it in the question just to show what I have done trying to solve this problem. Thanks

Comment: did u fix this? I have opened a new question asking similar thing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72774839/find-the-third-vertex-of-an-equilateral-trainable-given-two-n-dimensional-vertec

Comment: @FaridAlijani I could not